# Tailwind CSS Sliding Animation is not working

Tags: reactjs, animation, tailwind-css, sidebar

Even though the animation property is placed, the animation doesn't work. The sidebar simply pops up instead of sliding from right off screen to left.

```
import React from 'react'
import {MdClose} from 'react-icons/md'
import {BsCheck} from 'react-icons/bs'
import { themeColors } from '../data/dummy'
import { useStateContext } from '../contexts/ContextProvider'

export default function ThemeSettings() {
    const {setColor, setMode, currentMode, currentColor, setIsOpen} = useStateContext()
  return (
    <div className='bg-half-transparent font-signika nav-item relative'>
        <div className='w-full shadow-2xl xs:w-[70vw] md:w-[40vw] xl:w-[30vw] h-full fixed dark:text-white dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg bg-white top-0 right-0 transition-all duration-700}'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-2xl'>Settings</p>
                <button type='button' onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}  className='text-2xl p-3 rounded-full dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-slate-600 hover:bg-gray-400'>
                    <MdClose/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className='flex-col border-t-1 border-color p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-xl'>Theme Options</p>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <input type="radio" id='light' name='theme' value='Light' className='cursor-pointer' onChange={setMode} checked={currentMode === 'Light'}/>
                    <label htmlFor="light" className='text-md cursor-pointer ml-2'>Light</label>
                </div>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <input type="radio" id='dark' name='theme' value='Dark' className='cursor-pointer' onChange={setMode} checked={currentMode === 'Dark'}/>
                    <label htmlFor="dark" className='text-md cursor-pointer ml-2'>Dark</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex-col border-t-1 border-color p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-xl'>Theme Colors</p>
                <div className='flex gap-3'>
                    {themeColors.map((item) => (
                       <div className='relative mt-2 curosr-pointer flex gap-5 items-center'>
                        <button type='button'className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer' style={{backgroundColor: item.color}} onClick={() => setColor(item.color)}>
                            <BsCheck className={`ml-2 text-2xl text-white ${item.color === currentColor ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}/>
                        </button>
                       </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Do you think the problem could be related to my context provider? on how I update the isOpen setIsOpen state

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext()
const initialState = {
    cart: false,
    notification: false,
    searchBar: false,
}

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true)
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(initialState)
    const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(undefined)
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('#03C9D7')
    const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState('Light')
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    

    const setMode = (e) => {
        setCurrentMode(e.target.value);
        localStorage.setItem('themeMode', e.target.value);
      };

      const setColor = (color) => {
        setCurrentColor(color);
        localStorage.setItem('colorMode', color);
      };

    const handleClick = (clicked) => {
        setIsClicked({...initialState, [clicked]: true})
    }

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ 
            activeMenu,
            setActiveMenu,
            isClicked,
            setIsClicked,
            handleClick,
            screenSize,
            setScreenSize, currentColor,
            currentMode,
            setColor,
            setMode,
            isOpen, 
            setIsOpen
         }}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

The event is triggered here in the navbar component:

`<NavButton customFunc={() => setIsOpen(true)} icon={<IoMdSettings />} />`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { HiMenu } from 'react-icons/hi'
import { BiSearch } from "react-icons/bi";
import { FaShoppingBasket, FaBell } from "react-icons/fa";
import { IoMdSettings } from "react-icons/io";
import avatar from '../data/avatar.jpg'
import { Cart, Notification, SearchBar, ThemeSettings } from './Index'
import { useStateContext } from '../contexts/ContextProvider';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
  
  const { activeMenu, setActiveMenu, isClicked, setIsOpen, setThemeSettings, handleClick, screenSize, setScreenSize  } = useStateContext()
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleResize = () => setScreenSize(window.innerWidth);

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (screenSize <= 900) {
        setActiveMenu(false);
      } else {
        setActiveMenu(true);
      }
    }, [screenSize]);

    const handleOpenSidebar = () => {
      console.log('handleOpenSidebar executed');
      setIsOpen(true);
    };



  const NavButton = ({ customFunc, icon, dotColor, display, color }) => (
    <button
      id='navbutton'
      type="button"
      onClick={customFunc}
      className={`relative ${display} dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 dark:hover:text-white text-xl p-3 text-slate-500 hover:text-slate-700`}
      style={{ color }}>
      <span
        style={{ background: dotColor }}
        className="absolute inline-flex h-2 w-2 rounded-full right-3 top-3"
      />
      {icon}
    </button>
  ); 
  return (
    <div className="flex mx-5 justify-between lg:mt-7 xs:mt-5 xs:mb-5 relative">
      <div className="flex">
        {activeMenu ? (
          <div className="hidden">
            <NavButton />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="disabled">
            <NavButton
              customFunc={() =>
                setActiveMenu((prevActiveMenu) => !prevActiveMenu)
              }
              icon={<HiMenu />}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        {activeMenu ? (
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="search-navbar"
              class="hidden md:w-[400px] lg:block w-[700px] dark:outline-slate-200 outline-gray-400 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-700 p-3 pl-7 text-sm"
              placeholder="Search for Books..."
            ></input>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <NavButton
              customFunc={() => {
                handleClick("searchBar");
              }}
              icon={<BiSearch />}
              display="lg:hidden"
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="flex">
        <div className='mr-5'>
          <NavButton
            customFunc={() => setIsOpen(true)}
            icon={<IoMdSettings />}
          />
          <NavButton
            customFunc={() => {
              handleClick("cart");
            }}
            icon={<FaShoppingBasket />}
          />
          <NavButton
            customFunc={() => {
              handleClick("notification");
            }}
            icon={<FaBell />}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center pt-0 cursor-pointer rounded-lg">
          <Link to="/userProfile">
            <img src={avatar} alt="" className="rounded-full w-8 h-8" />
          </Link>
        </div>
        {isClicked.cart && <Cart />}
        {isClicked.notification && <Notification />}
        {isClicked.searchBar && <SearchBar />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).